# Make more evident when an action is not possible

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

I was reviewing the posts flagged for moderation attention. One of those was an answer that was not an answer, and the possible actions for that post included the "convert to comment" action.

[image: screenshot]

Clicking of the "convert to comment" button didn't have any effect; the reason is probably that there are comments for that post, but that is not clear. The button is simply disabled (i.e. the HTML "disabled" attribute is used for that button), even if it is not possible to see any difference between an enabled button, and a disabled button (e.g. there isn't any visual difference between the "convert to comment," and the "no further action…" buttons).

The disabled buttons should use a different style, or clicking on those buttons should show a dialog box that makes clear the reason why the action cannot be performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been implemented: The button is now shown with a different transparency.

[image: screenshot]